# Resize a pane in javafx by dragging it

Tags: javafx

I have 2 pane the bigger one and the smaller one. I want to make the smaller pane resize by dragging it accordingly ; just the way a window works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the panes, except `Group` are re-sizable in `JavaFx`. Just make sure you have, your resizable property of the stage as `true`.

The *default* value is `true` !

```
stage.setResizable(true);
```

Comment: Its not the stage that I want to resize but just a pane which is inside other pane

Comment: All the panes are self resizable in javafx, you don't have to worry about it. If there is a particular scenario that you are worried about, give an example that doesn't work for you !

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the scenario that I want to make a pane resizable http://imageshack.com/a/img713/2062/1lfb.png   The light grey is a pane which has a dark grey pane inside it. I want to resize the dark grey pane.

Comment: Somebody please help we with this. This answer is certainly what I am looking for and is not correct.

Comment: which pane are you using for the center?

Comment: this was a very complex code to do. I have completed this by using two more class files and creating the object in the main class and setting the properties. Download the code here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7swqjuq1s04ilcq/AABSMiARnU_XuqqUhpJOZIM2a